# Core Data: managedObjectContext where to use performBlock or performBlockAndWait

Tags: multithreading, core-data, parent-child, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Using the `Parent/Child` context model for using `Core Data` with `multithreading`, when should you be calling the `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` functions?

Should they be called only when saving the changes from the `Child context` to the `Parent context`? Thus, after you have already made the changes to the Core Data records (in the child context)?

Or would you call `performBlock` while you are doing the actual changes to the Core Data records? As well as when saving the changes to the child then parent contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you should always use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` when doing any operation involving that context, including just reading objects. The only exceptions are main queue contexts (where you can use `performBlock:` if you wish, but there's no requirement to if you're on the main thread), and thread confinement contexts (which are deprecated anyway, and you likely have no reason to use anymore.)

Comment: Thanks for succinct answer Andy. On a side note, do you know a tutorial or example of using the Parent/Child context model? (preferably in Swift, those are hard to find!)

Comment: Not aware of any Swift-specific examples, but it really is as simple as setting the `parentContext` property on the child and experimenting with how changes are passed between the two. Some of the behavior may surprise you. (It certainly did me.) I don't recommend using child contexts for anything other than temporary scratchpads that you may decide to save soon or discard, which when saved force their changes upon their parent with no consideration for merge policy. Any of our contexts which live for a while (for instance, syncing contexts) tie directly to the persistent store coordinator.